# Django Plotly Dash

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have learned plotly and Dash, which are data visualisations library in python. Though i have got their core concepts and also i am well versed in django python as well, i dont know to integrate dash and plotly in django rest framework. I have searched everywhere but it seems there is a lack of resources on this topic. I want to create a dashboard using the same , just like we create dashboards using front end languages. Please help, i have been searching but not able to get any resources for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you already answered your question?